# How to remove git commits from master branch but keep them in other branches?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I created two commits in master branch in local. And I don't want them to be in the master. So I branch out from master to a separate branch with thi s command `git checkout -b new-branch` and pushed this branch to github. After that these two commits exist in both `new-branch` and `master` branches. How can I delete these two commits from `master` but keep them in `new-branch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't push those commits yet, you need to reset master after creatiing your branch:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard @~2
```

That will remove the last two commits from the master branch.

If those commits are not the last two, you need to find the reference of the oldest commit you want to remove (say SHA1 '`X`') and do an interactive rebase.

```
git checkout master
git rebase X~
```

You will be able to drop those two commits from your master branch.
But you might have to rebase your newly created branch in order to change its base to the new master HEAD:

```
git checkout new-branch
git rebase --onto master new-branch~2 new-branch
```

If you have already pushed master, but you are alone working on that repo, you can also consider that approach (and `git push --force` your master branch)